# Umbraco Macros Appear to be Rendering Two or More Times

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

Upon debugging my Umbraco solution (which was given to me by an outside consulting firm) and checking my error logs, I have noticed that it would appear that my macros are being hit in the code anywhere between 2 and 5 times. The macro isn't rendered that many times, it is just logging a warning and stepping through the code that many times.

Why is this? Is this basic Umbraco functionality or is there a mistake in my code?

My view under the Views -> MacroPartials folder looks like this:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.MacroParameters["title"].ToString()))
{        
    <h2 class="@(Model.MacroParameters["hideBorder"].ToString() == "1" ? "" : "heading-border")">@Html.Raw(Model.MacroParameters["title"])</h2>
}
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.MacroParameters["subTitle"].ToString()))
{
    <h2 class="large-body-copy">@Html.Raw(Model.MacroParameters["subTitle"])</h2>
}
```

Here is how I have the macro set up in the back office:
[image]

Comment: this is not a default umbraco behavior. can you share your code block to get an idea?

Comment: Hi @DimuthuNilanka I have updated the post with my code and a screen shot of the back office.

Comment: can you also include the code from view that call to macro eg: @Umbraco.RenderMacro("Title SubTitle")

Comment: I'm not sure how far we are going to be able to go. We are using abstraction to make it more generic so that a macro can be selected. 

We have a Macro.cshtml file that has this:

`@inherits UmbracoViewPage<dynamic>

@if (Model.value != null)
{
    string macroAlias = Model.value.macroAlias.ToString();
    ViewDataDictionary parameters = new ViewDataDictionary();
    foreach (dynamic mpd in Model.value.macroParamsDictionary)
    {
        parameters.Add(mpd.Name, mpd.Value);
    }

    <text>
        @Umbraco.RenderMacro(macroAlias, parameters)
    </text>
}`

Comment: I've noticed that we are using the Umbraco Ditto Service, though I'm unsure if that is related to macros or not.